# i can't redirect to next registration page when i click on to SIGN IN button

Tags: android

basically am a java developer but now am developing an android app.In my app i can't redirect to the next page when i click on to SIGN IN button and here is my code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button log,sign;



@Override


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.login);


    log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);


    log.setOnClickListener(this);
    sign.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()) {
      case R.id.login:
        break;
      case R.id.signup:
          Intent open = new Intent("com.example.eblood.Register");
          startActivity(open);

        break;
    }
}




}
}
```

Here is my next page java code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Register extends Activity{
Button backlog,regg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
     backlog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.linktologin);
     regg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
     backlog.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}
     public void onClick (View v)
     {

            switch(v.getId()) {
              case R.id.register:
                break;
              case R.id.linktologin:
                  Intent in = new    Intent("com.example.eblood.MainActivity");
                  startActivity(in);
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Here is my manifest code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.eblood"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.eblood.home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.eblood.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.eblood.MAINACTIVITY" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.eblood.Register"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REGISTER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



</application>
```

and the error am getting is android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.eblood.Register }

And here is my home.java

```
package com.example.eblood;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class home extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(2000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.example.eblood.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
            }
    }
    };
    timer.start();}{
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

If you use `Intent open = new Intent("com.example.eblood.Register");` you will get `ActivityNotFoundException` change it as `Intent open = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);`

Change this

```
Intent open = new Intent("com.example.eblood.Register");
startActivity(open);
```

to

```
Intent open = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
startActivity(open);
```

also

change this

```
Intent in = new Intent("com.example.eblood.MainActivity");
startActivity(in);
```

to

```
Intent in = new Intent(Register.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
```

**EDIT**

Change this.

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.example.eblood.MAINACTIVITY");
startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

to

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(home.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

Comment: Still am getting the error ActivityNotFoundException.i think i need to change something in manifest code.

Comment: @user3550911 remove `intent-filter` from manifest and try. like my edit.

Comment: if i paste that above code in my manifest it gives me error as duplicate registration for activity because i alredy used       <activity
    android:name="com.example.eblood.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>

Comment: @user3550911 also post your home activity.

Comment: but in your edit you have not declared any action,even if i remove and paste your code i wont get my login page itself..

Comment: I have posted.see my home.java in my question

Comment: where can i see your edited code..??actually am new to asking the question so am asking please don't mind

Comment: @user3550911 in your home.java change it like my edit.

Comment: ,first part is working but from login to registration page is not directing if i click sign up button

Comment: i will get my login screen now have not assigned anything to login button,if i click sign up button it has to go for register page but when i click sign up button my app will ask for force close and in logcat i will get the error as android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.eblood.Register }

Comment: @user3550911 i didn't get clearly. while clicking sign up button screen goes to `Register.java`. Is that working.

Comment: that's the problem what am experiencing my signup click is not working.

Comment: if i click signup button my app will be force closed and use to get error in logcat as android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.eblood.Register }

Comment: @user3550911 have you change this `Intent open = new Intent("com.example.eblood.Register");` as this `Intent open = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);`

Comment: ya sir i have changed what you have told but still experiencing the same error

Comment: @AdarshaAP Clean and Built your project.

Comment: let me do that now sir,as you think i have no error in my code is that rite...???

Comment: still it is not getting correct but any how thank you for your response sir